# VBA Match/Index function that skips any string cells or jumps iterations

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets that I am trying to pull force values from one to the other. 
I am searching column C for any cells that start with Force-X and then counting down and grabbing all the values.

The issue I am running into is that the sheet that I currently pull from has random string values in the middle of the cells. This is generated by a program called Femap and I can't control the texts.
Here is an example of what I am pulling from.

```
ELEMENT-ID  FORCE-X
38789   1.06E+00
38795   2.49E+00
38801   2.30E+00
38807   2.21E+00
38813   2.15E+00
38819   1.90E+00
38825   1.57E+00
38827   -8.43E-01
38833   3.92E+00
38839   1.51E+01
38845   1.68E+01
38851   1.19E+01
38857   9.22E+00
38863   2.84E+00

**CBUSH-CRITS   JULY
CONSTRAINT  SET
SUBCASE 1

F   O**

ELEMENT-ID  FORCE-X
39721   8.80E+00
39727   6.02E+00
39733   1.44E+00
```

Problem area is in bold. My cells end up having values such as July, Constraint Set, etc. How can I skip any cells with a string and ensure my index search just grabs values from one iteration of Force-X onto the next iteration of Force-X.

```
Dim mrsheet As Worksheet

Set mrsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPO")



'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
n = 2
Count = 1
m = 1
numcbush = 138
i = 1


While m <= numcbush


If Sheets("F06").Cells(i, 2) = mrsheet.Cells(n, 1) Then

     mrsheet.Cells(n, 12) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("F06").Range("C:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("FORCE-X", Sheets("F06").Range("C:C"), 0) + Count)

      m = m + 1
      n = n + 1
      Count = Count + 1
      i = i + 1

Else


i = i + 1

End If



Wend
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this macro first to clean your data before you start your procedure? **Make sure you backup, this will delete rows!!**

```
Sub CleanupData()
Dim aCell As Range

StartClean:
For Each aCell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")).Cells

If IsNumeric(aCell) Or InStr(1, UCase(aCell.Text), "FORCE-X") > 0 Or IsEmpty(aCell) Then
    'do nothing
Else
    aCell.EntireRow.Delete
    GoTo StartClean
End If

Next

End Sub
```